# What has happened to the twitter account of the site?

Tags: discussion

I... well... we could say that not twitter is the most liked global content provider by me.

But, for me it is important in the question histories, if they were shared on the twitter. And it is also a way for the site, to get a lot of visitors.

The [current state](https://twitter.com/StackUnix) of the site twitter account shows a big block.

The [last snapshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20200114175715/https://twitter.com/StackUnix/status/1211572774994661378) I could dig out from the archive.org, shows that it worked yet in 2020-01-14.

What has happened?

Comment: Is that the official site account? Anyway, when I click on your link I see a clear message saying that the account is suspended and that `Twitter suspends accounts which violate the Twitter Rules`. So this account, whatever it is, seems to be suspended. Frankly, if it is the site's account, then lets let it _stay_ suspended so it doesn't tweet the worst questions we have any more?

Comment: @terdon I got to this twitter page from the history page of my [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/542270/revisions) old question. (And I visited this history page because recently I've got 3 ups to it and I thought maybe something revived it.) Yes, it looks very well to the ordinary site account.

Comment: @terdon Without taking a side about the usefulness of this account (btw, note what I said about twitter), this question is only about, what is going on.

Comment: The official list ([source](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/12/twitter-question-feeds-for-stack-exchange/)) of per-site Twitter accounts is in [stackexchange.com/sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic), and having a link there which points to a suspended account seems... suboptimal.

Comment: @fra-san I think the company will check, what is going on, possibly a mod will alert them on their channels. Although I don't believe that twitter attracts the best content, here we are to convert the fresh meat to improving stats.

Comment: @terdon et al: I've reached out to the CM's for a company response.